# How to stop a loop when using attachInterrupt to catch the change of a button

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, interrupt, piezo, loop

This what the program does:

> There is 1 button to start/stop the engine, when the motor is running
>   the green LED will go on, when stopped the red LED is on. The second
>   button is used to change the direction of the DC-motor. When the
>   temperature is above 20° the motor will stop and the servo motor will
>   go to the position of the red LED. Otherwise the servo motor is in a
>   neutral position. When the engine is running there a music playing that should sound as a car.

So what my problem is if I pressed the button to stop the DC-motor but the music is still playing it won't stop. I read something about a [break](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.Break). Can you combine this with the `attachInterrupt()`? I also found something called [`interrupts()` and `noInterrupts()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/interrupts/interrupts/). What do I need to so when I pressed the button the DC-Motor directly stops and the led turns red?

The init

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include "notebook.h";
#include "themes.h";

const int input1OfTheDCMotor = 9;
const int input2OfTheDCMotor = 10;
const int pwmInputOfTheDCMotor = 6;
const int buttonToStartStopTheDcMotor = 2;
const int buttonToShowToChangeTheDirectionOfTheDCMotor = 3;
const int greenLed = 12;
const int redLed = 8;
const int tempSensor = A0;
const int servoPin = 11;
Servo servo;


volatile byte stateOfTheButtonToStartStopTheDCMotor = LOW;
bool isRunning = LOW;
bool changeDirection = LOW;
bool isEngineSoundsPlaying = HIGH;
```

The `setup()`

```
void setup() {
  //Leds setup
  pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
  //buttons
  pinMode(buttonToStartStopTheDcMotor, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonToShowToChangeTheDirectionOfTheDCMotor, INPUT);
  //DC motor
  pinMode(input1OfTheDCMotor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(input2OfTheDCMotor, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(input1OfTheDCMotor, LOW);
  digitalWrite(input2OfTheDCMotor, HIGH);
  //pwm signal
  pinMode(pwmInputOfTheDCMotor, OUTPUT);
  //Servo
  servo.attach(servoPin);
  //interrupts
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonToStartStopTheDcMotor), readTheChangeToStartStop, RISING );
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonToShowToChangeTheDirectionOfTheDCMotor), readTheChangeToChangeDirection, RISING );
}
```

The `loop()`

```
void loop() {
  int valueOfTheSensor = analogRead(tempSensor);
  float voltage = (valueOfTheSensor / 1024.0) * 5.0;
  float temp = (voltage -0.5) * 100;
  if (temp >= 20.00) 
    isRunning = LOW;
  }
  changeTheStateOfTheLights(isRunning);
  startTheDCMotorAndStopIt(isRunning);
  changeTheDirectionOfTheDCMotor(changeDirection);
}
```

The function `readTheChangeToStartStop()`:

```
void readTheChangeToStartStop () {
  isRunning  = !isRunning;
  changeTheStatusOfTheEnginePlaying();
}
```

The function `readTheChangeToChangeDirection()`:

```
void readTheChangeToChangeDirection () {
  changeDirection = !changeDirection;
}
```

The function `changeTheStatusOfTheEnginePlaying()`:

```
void changeTheStatusOfTheEnginePlaying (){
  if (isRunning == HIGH){
    isEngineSoundsPlaying = HIGH;
  } else {
    isEngineSoundsPlaying = LOW;
  }
}
```

The function `changeTheStateOfTheLights()`:

```
void changeTheStateOfTheLights(bool stateOfLight) {
  digitalWrite(greenLed, stateOfLight);
  digitalWrite(redLed, !stateOfLight);
}
```

The function `startTheDCMotorAndStopIt()`:

```
void startTheDCMotorAndStopIt(bool isRunning){
  if (isRunning == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(pwmInputOfTheDCMotor, HIGH);
    playCarMusicStart();
    changeToNeutral();
  } else {
    digitalWrite(pwmInputOfTheDCMotor, LOW);
    changeToRedLight();
  }
}
```

The function `changeTheDirectionOfTheDCMotor()`:

```
void changeTheDirectionOfTheDCMotor(bool changeDirection) {
  digitalWrite(input1OfTheDCMotor, changeDirection);
  digitalWrite(input2OfTheDCMotor, !changeDirection);
}
```

The function `changeToRedLight()`:

```
void changeToRedLight() {
  servo.write(0);
  delay(15);
}
```

The function `changeToNeutral()`:

```
void changeToNeutral() {
  servo.write(40);
  delay(15);
}
```

The function `playCarMusicStart()`:

```
void playCarMusicStart(){
  if (isEngineSoundsPlaying == HIGH) {
    for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < (sizeof(carSounds_note)/sizeof(int)); thisNote++) {
      int noteDuration = 1000 / carsounds_duration[thisNote];
      tone(4, carSounds_note[thisNote], noteDuration);
      int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 2.70;
      delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
      noTone(4); 
      isEngineSoundsPlaying = LOW;
    }
  }
}
```

## Solution

### A big thanks to @ratchet freak

I need to change my `loop()` to this:

```
void loop() {
  int valueOfTheSensor = analogRead(tempSensor);
  float voltage = (valueOfTheSensor / 1024.0) * 5.0;
  float temp = (voltage -0.5) * 100;
  if (temp >= 20.00) {
    isRunning = LOW;
  }
  changeTheStateOfTheLights(isRunning);
  startTheDCMotorAndStopIt(isRunning);
  changeTheDirectionOfTheDCMotor(changeDirection);


  playCarMusicStart();
}
```

I also needed to change the `PlayCarMusicStart()`:

```
void playCarMusicStart(){
  if (isEngineSoundsPlaying == HIGH && currentNote < (sizeof(carSounds_note)/sizeof(int))) {
      int noteDuration = 1000 / carsounds_duration[currentNote];
      tone(4, carSounds_note[currentNote], noteDuration);
      int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 2.70;
      delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
      noTone(4);
      currentNote++;
   } else {
      currentNote = 0;
   }
}
```

And the least is to set the `isEngineSoundsPlaying` equal to `HIGH`, I changed the function `startTheDCMotorAndStopIt()` for:

```
void startTheDCMotorAndStopIt(bool isRunning){
  if (isRunning == HIGH) {
    isEngineSoundsPlaying = HIGH;
    digitalWrite(pwmInputOfTheDCMotor, HIGH);
    changeToNeutral();
  } else {
    isEngineSoundsPlaying = LOW;
    digitalWrite(pwmInputOfTheDCMotor, LOW);
    changeToRedLight();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key will be to split up `playCarMusicStart` and instead create a `playCarMusicStep` that will do just one iteration of the loop and returns. Call it every time in `loop()` akin to blinkWithoutDelay.

In playCarMusicStart you then setup the playing state so it starts playing correctly.

And when you need to stop it you then stop the music by setting the correct variable.

Comment: You mean this with blinkWithoutDelay https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay

Comment: The music loops takes 7400ms so when I pressed the button how can I stopped immediately without waiting 7400ms

Comment: by returning immediately after starting the music and calling the function again when new processing needs to occur for the next note/pauze

Comment: Thanks I updated the question with the solution a big thanks for helping me!